# How do I use renderFile()?

Tags: symfony1, symfony-1.4

I'm trying to make an action render to a file rather than output to the browser. I thought I would just have to do this:

```
return sfPHPView::renderFile('filename');
```

like I would with sfView, but that gives me an error:

> Fatal error: Call to protected method sfPHPView::renderFile() from context...

What am I doing wrong?

Here's a link to the symfony API: [sfPHPView::renderFile()](http://www.symfony-project.org/api/1_4/sfPHPView#method_renderfile)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`renderFile()` is a method to render FROM a template file. That's why it isn't working.

Comment: Ah I see. Missed that! Thanks.